# Converting a class with a property of T to and from json

Tags: vb.net

I have a class (MyMessage) which have a property called "Settings" of Type T.

I need to convert MyMessage to json, send it via TCP and when I recieve it, I need to test what class Type T is and then convert the recieved json to the MyMessage Of T class.

This is my code so far - function SendMessage and MessageRecieved is not working ... and I need your help :)...

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim t As New MyMessage(Of MyMessageSettingsText)
        t.Settings.Text = "Yes"
        Call SendMessage(t)

        Dim n As New MyMessage(Of MyMessageSettingsNumber)
        n.Settings.Number = 1
        Call SendMessage(n)
    End Sub

    Private Sub SendMessage(msg As MyMessage)
        Dim json As String = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(msg)
        ' Do send using tcp etc
    End Sub

    Private Sub MessageRecieved(msgJson As String) ' A json string recived from a tcp server
        Dim msg As MyMessage = DirectCast(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of MyMessage)(msgJson), MyMessage)
        If TypeOf (msg.Settings) Is MyMessageSettingsText Then
            Dim t As MyMessage(Of MyMessageSettingsText) = CType(msg, MyMessage(Of MyMessageSettingsText))
            ' do something with t
        End If
    End Sub    
End Class


Public MustInherit Class MyMessageSettingsBase
End Class


Public Class MyMessageSettingsText
    Inherits MyMessageSettingsBase
    Public Property Text As String
End Class


Public Class MyMessageSettingsNumber
    Inherits MyMessageSettingsBase
    Public Property Number As Integer
End Class


Public Class MyMessage(Of T As {New})
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Settings As New T
End Class
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages or whay is it not working?

Comment: The SendMessage doesn't like the MyMessage param ... Too few type arguments to 'MyMessage(Of T As New)' ... and the same goes for the Dim msg as Mymessage in the MessageRecieved function